# How To Add two Textbox values with jquery and also add two more textboxs that are apend from the same textboxs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnWCv.png)this is simple text boxes i give the value and add them ![enter image description here][2]
when I add more text boxes with append query now the sum is not calculating

[enter image description here][3]

[THis is jquery code of  iam  apending two divs with Two ids and text boxes are also have there ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnWCv.png)

Comment: would you add a code snippet please?

Comment: can you insert the code so see what is the problem?

Comment: how To Add code snippet ('_') here i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Take tour of this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) @Shahab

Comment: i just add  code image above i  havn't so many reputation so i  cant add many images at a time

Comment: For adding code or asking questions reputation doesn't matter..Check my code and example@Shahab

Comment: @Nidhi  thankx for helping thats i want and you provide me thankx again for help  ..

Comment: Glad to help you. Can you please upvote it@Shahab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery features for implement complex thing in a very easier way...

It provides Huge Library with number of functions and Flexibility for executing your code in cross browsers

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-more">ADD MORE</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="ele">
  <div class="row" id="item1">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="number" class="num1">
      <label>+</label>
      <input type="number" class="num2">
      <label>SUM</label>
      <input type="number" class="sum" readonly="true">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success remove">x</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY Script**

```
var item = $('#item1').html();
var cnt = 0;
$('.add-more').click(function() {
  cnt++;
  $('#ele').append("<div class='row' id='item" + cnt + "'>" + item + "</div>");
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.num1,.num2', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('num1')) {
    var num1 = parseInt($(this).val());
    var num2 = parseInt($(this).siblings('.num2').val());
    $(this).siblings('.sum').val(num1 + num2);
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('num2')) {
    var num2 = parseInt($(this).val());
    var num1 = parseInt($(this).siblings('.num1').val());
    $(this).siblings('.sum').val(num1 + num2);
  }
});
```

[Check Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/99tzxev7/)